# node-mysql dependant program runs only in the /node_modules/node-mysql folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I have a node-mysql program

```
node db.js

   module.js: 340 
   throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
```

the error is @

```
var mysql      = require('mysql'); //for node-mysql
```

The error goes away and it all works when I run the program in the nodemodules/node-mysql/ directory, which is sort of lame, considering the other packages I have used are nothing like that, I think.

Is it deliberate for security purposes or am I doing it wrong?

> I am damn near certain this question has been asked before, however I couldn't find an actual answer when I searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up two different MySQL packages:

- [`node-mysql`](https://npmjs.org/package/node-mysql), installed with `npm install node-mysql`;
- [`mysql`](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql), installed with `npm install mysql`, and on [GitHub](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) confusingly called `node-mysql`;

You installed the first one, which installs in `node_modules/node-mysql/` and should be loaded using `require('node-mysql')`.

If you install the second one (which I think you want, anyway), it'll install in `node_modules/mysql/` and your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

rename your `node_modules/node-mysql` to `node_modules/mysql`. When you `require` package_name npm searches ./node_modules/package_name, then ../node_modules/package_name etc, then global locations.